# Protect ajax files from direct call using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

To prevent my Ajax files from direct acccess I did this:

I put all files in a common directory called "ajax" and put this in an .htaccess file in the same folder. This is my directory structure:

`/var/www/html/ajax`

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/ajax">
   order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

But this produces server error 500. .htaccess use is enabled in my server along with mod-rewrite. Please help.

Comment: Usually, 500 errors are explained in Apache's (?) error.log. What's yours say? (I'm guessing, though, it's because `Order` is in small caps in your .htaccess)

Comment: @LinusKleen  this is the error. [Tue Dec 20 19:12:24 2011] [alert] [client my-ip] /var/www/html/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here.   Also changed o to caps but error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

The Directory directive is not allowed in your .htaccess file. see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory.  However, you can achieve the same result by simply placing the code you have in the .haccess in the `/var/www/html/ajax` directory, without the `Directory` directive

```
order allow,deny
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: yes ... the server error problem has gone ... but the directory ajax is now not even accessible by the browser.

Comment: If you are accessing the content from 127.0.0.1, then it should work. What ip address is your browser on?

Comment: You have to change "127.0.0.1" to your IP address.

Comment: I guess then i need altogether a different solution. I was trying to implement this to prevent access to files in ajax folder so that they cannot be called directly but calling them in browser url ex:-   www.mysite.com/ajax/comment.php?act=12210&id=203  like this.  comment.php is an ajax called file. it should not be called directly by users. but some malicious one's may try this. how to prevent it. please suggest me a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`<Directory>` is a directive that's not supported in `.htaccess` files, it's [core and vhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#directory) specific.

For an `.htaccess` file, the directive is superfluous and must be omitted, because the directory is implied by the location of the `.htaccess` file.

Simply remove `<Directory>` and its closing "tag" and it should work.

Comment: but by allowing override in httpd.conf can i not specify this directive here.?

Comment: No, not by allowing override or anything else. The `<Directory>` directive is *specifically* bound to .conf files.

Comment: you mean                                                     "/var/www/html/ajax"
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1    .... but this is also not working.

Comment: actually sir i have not arrived at the solution still.